Three kilometers (~2 miles high) tsunamis go around the Earth - what kinds of ruins are left?
I am (still) writing some fiction about the solar system being rearranged, with the Earth losing the Moon. But before she goes, I am having her do a close flyby.
My story is actually happening millennia after the fact. I am trying to come up with some worldbuilding that realistically reflects the destruction caused by such an event, and how much descendants of the survivors of the cataclysm can recover and parse from the past via whatever ruins are left.
I have seen this video from Kurzgesagt where they say that should the Moon come very close to Earth, the tides would pull the oceans into 3km high waves (about 2 miles high, in imperial measure) going around the globe. There would also be global earthquakes and apocalyptic meteor showers, but I think the waves would be the most of the pounding on cities, right?
So the question is what kind of ruins would be left if the oceans were pulled and dragged over the continents in tsunami form. Back of napkin calculation tells me that does for 300 bar for the water column alone pressing on a building, which makes for three Venusians atmospheres, but I don't know what that would do to a city as a whole and what archeology could be done to whatever remains.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Location, location, location
Coast
Coastal cities would be razed to the ground. Bridge foundations tend to be reinforced concrete that's well anchored and stabilized against forces parallel to the river flow, so some of that might survive.
Even then, some underground structures could survive.
Probably not basements, but think of subway tunnels. They would get flooded and lots of debris entering, so the entry areas will be a mess, but farther in, friction will slow down the inrush, and you may even find that the water pressing in near the beach will keep entries further up free because of displaced air being blown out at the just right time.
The inside of such an underground structure would have been a deathtrap, and it's somewhat unlikely that entrances would stay accessible, but some freak tunnels might be there for the descendants to wonder about.
Further inland
Distance from the coast will dissipate energy via ground friction.
Terrain height will eat energy that goes into height, though water piling up will regain that energy when rushing down the terrain.
Result
You get absolute devastation near the coastlines. Most cities won't be recognizable as such, but descendants will see all kinds of broken artifacts. Possibly some plastics, some metal fragments. Roads will still stand out because of terrain shaping and because there will be remnants of road surface material, foundations will still be present even if as caved-in depressions filled with concrete rubble. Foundations for bridges and high-volt power lines have no hollow inside so they will be rubble with a more-or-less solid core.
Further away from the coast, the underground stuff will likely be the same but more of above-ground structures will stay discernible. It will be a gradual change until you get to a region where the tsunami never arrived - there are mountains higher than 2000 meters, and horizontal terrain will stop even the highest tsunami. Eventually.

Just so. The interiors of continents will not be affected by the tsunami.

So, Mongolia prevails!

You can look at some historical example to get a sense for what would happen.
On October 9th 1963, a landslide in the Vajont dam caused a tsunami wave 250 meters tall which swept the valley below the dam, bringing death along its course.
This is what was left of a village right below the dam


as you can see it's hard to tell that there was a village there at all. The dam itself was left untouched and still stands there, but I can imagine that a wave 12 times taller would have little mercy also of reinforced concrete.
I think you would be left with scorched ground with, here and there, some leftover from a very lucky or sturdy building.
The ocean would be littered with debris which would bear little similarity to the buildings from which they originated. For example I don't expect a brick wall to hold together while being carried along from the wave, and the crushing during the transportation would drastically affect also the shape of the individual bricks.

The water pressure 3km deep should make the wave even stronger.  I don't think there will be anything left.  I would think even roadways would be gone; it will rip up the asphalt.

@Ryan_L Depth does not change a lot. The overall pressure gets higher, but it's the pressure differential that moves things around, and since water is largely incompressible, the push will the the same whether you have 1 km or 3 km of water above the flow. The flow will be tremendous and rip everything up; things like slopes and hill incisions have a better survival chance, and the higher up or the more inland you are, the more will be left.

Ask and Youtube shall provide! There is this video produced by a scientist who studies tsunamis, which shows a very similar thing to what you have in mind. The premise of the video is slightly different (his hypothetical scenario is that the solid Earth stopped rotating) but the simulation produces waves up to 4 km tall, so in the same ballpark.
The most striking thing is just how fast such tall waves are. They have no problem crossing whole continents in an afternoon. This speed, and not the pressure as such, would be the single biggest destructive factor: the rushing water would effectively apply an enormous amount of torque to any structure sticking out of the ground and snap it off at the base, and then carry it and inevitably smash it into other things and pick these up in turn. It will also have no problem washing out the soil from underneath structures. After the initial wave energy mostly dissipates, water will drain from the interiors of the continents back to the ocean basins and carry the debris with it, where it will be mostly buried in the washed out soil and any other sediment the wave would have picked.
In terms of archeology, not much at all will be left. Most man-made objects will be either smeared haphazardly over the vast deltas deposited by the receding waters, or would have eventually found its way to the bottom of the abyssal plains, and mixed with other debris in both cases. After several millenia, most metal objects would have rusted beyond recognition, and even large blocks of concrete and masonry may have accumulated quite a lot of damage from whatever chemical reactions have been slowly occurring between them and their new environment. Most importantly, even such objects as do survive will be deprived of their original context and therefore difficult to interpret.

The video reports the tsunami waves as 10 km high. Now that's three times of what the OP asked, and definitely not the same ballpark I'd say. Those 4 kms are the typical height after washing over a continent, so the waves lose 6 kms of height, which is an awesome decrease and also underlines that the effects are very different.

Disagree on nothing left.  Yes, humanity would be scoured from the surface of the Earth.  Some mines would survive, albeit flooded at least for a while.

I agree with @toolforger:  when the tsunami jumps up the continental plateau on the Western coast of N. Am., its crest is shown ~5km above "sea level". This is the conventional zero altitude, not the free surface of the water behind it, which is ~ minus 3km. I call this a 8km high tsunami, jumping 3km over the crestline of the Western cordillera. https://youtu.be/6oT1_j0Am7Y?t=279

Also, these tsunamis arise from every single molecule of oceanic water, however deep, accelerating eastwards w/resp to the Earth crust: from 0 to ~450m/s at the Equator, to ~300m/s at +/- 45° lat., all in sync over a few minutes. Hard to imagine a geologically plausible scenario to the same effect.

@toolforger, thank you. Not exactly though; 10 km is a theoretical maximum height if there was no friction. But there always is friction. And so the model shows the waves being up to 4 km, which of course means that most of the waves are lower still.

@FrançoisJurain, thank you. Was the "3 km high" tsunami mentioned by OP measured from the sea level, or from the bottom of the wave's trough?

And also @FrançoisJurain, I'm not sure why you see geologic implausibility as problematic on Worldbuilding of all places... ;)

@ihaveideas I understand it measured when the tsunami breaks, so from crest to solid Earth crust. Which, near the shore, is from crest to trough, +/- a few hundred meters. The problem with implausible scenarios is, they make the OP's prospective tale too, ah, tall to be believed, which sort of defeats the point of posting here. And yes, the name Worldbuilding is a bit tall in this respect, if you will excuse my French.

@FrançoisJurain, thank you. I guess that's personal taste: I for one quite like those farfetched what-if scenarios. I don't need to believe them as such.

@ihaveideas The 10 km is the maximum height achievable when converting speed to height. So coastal bodies of water will start at 0 km elevation and reach 10 km minus frictional losses; in other words, the video is already a VERY different scenario than 3 km waves regardless of definitional details. For starters, it just overflows the entirety of both Americas, which a wave of 3 km height, even if it starts with that height at the coastline, simply cannot do because the Rockies are > 2 km high and the wave would lose height, and the Andes are > 5 km high.

@toolforger, thank you. Not quite; this is not as much 'a wave' as 'the ocean moving eastward at roughly the speed of sound'. The water immediately at the coast will continue to be pushed by the mass of water behind it, which will transfer some of its energy into the water ahead of it. In this way the water can reach above the initial wave height and keep going.
